# Проверка входящих данных на тип

Tags: java

Есть ДЗ, написать калькулятор в консоли, уперся в требование "Реализовать такую функциональность можно при помощи оператора instanceof." У меня есть `switch`:

```
    switch (operator) {
        case "+" :
            System.out.println(a + " " + operator + " " + b + " = " + Calc.sum(a,b));
            break;
        case "*" :
            System.out.println(a + " " + operator + " " + b + " = " + Calc.multiply(a, b));
            break;
        case "/" :
            System.out.println(a + " " + operator + " " + b + " = " + Calc.divided(a, b));
            break;
        case "-" :
            System.out.println(a + " " + operator + " " + b + " = " + Calc.minus(a, b));
            break;
    }
```

Методы в `switch` могут принимать следующие типы данных: `int`, `double`, `String`, они перегружаемые в классе `Calc`. Как мне изменять тип переменной, передаваемой в метод, исходя из введенных данных пользователем используя `instanceof`? Вот часть, где вводятся значения:

```
    System.out.print("Enter operator : ");
    String operator = scanner.next();

    System.out.print("Enter first operand : ");
    int a = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter second operand : ");
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
```